# File request returns an empty arrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch, arraybuffer

I try to get a PDF document from google firebase storage using fetch but there is an empty array buffer in the response.
`ArrayBuffer { byteLength: 0 }`

Here is my code-

```
const PDFDocsHandlers = this.documents.map(async (directoryDoc) => {
     const response = await fetch(directoryDoc.url, {
         mode: 'no-cors',
     })
     .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
         .then(arrayBuffer => {
            console.log(arrayBuffer);
            const PDFDoc = PDFDocument.load(arrayBuffer);
         })
     });
```

I expect to receive some data in the ArrayBuffer response so it can be loaded with PDFLib but it's not working because the PDFLib can't read empty array buffer.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61605078/axios-get-a-file-from-url-and-upload-to-s3/61621094#61621094) for the downloading part, it's with `axios`.

Comment: Do you want to handle the case such as there is no data, ie. the document is empty because it was there, but it was in a 'corrupted' state, such as there is no data instead of the bytes to represent the PDF file?